# hql order by returning wrong order

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have a function that creates an hql query and appends an order by clause dynamically, then executes the query.  The query returns the correct results but they are not in the order set by the order by.

```
public List<Event> Search(string sortby)
{
    string query = "from Event e and e.IsDeleted = 0 ";

    if (sortby != null && sortby != "")
    {
        var useDesc = sortby.EndsWith("Desc");

        var name = useDesc
            ? sortby.Remove(sortby.Length - 4, 4)
            : sortby;

        switch (name)
        {
            case "Name":
                query = query + " order by e.Name ";
                break;
            case "DateCreated":
                query = query + " order by e.CreatedOn ";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        query = useDesc ? query + " desc" : query + " asc";
    }

    var HqlQuery = session.CreateQuery(query);

    IList<Event> events = HqlQuery.List<Event>().ToList();

    return events;
}
```

Why is this returning the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the mapping, I could point out two issues

Firstly this query should be :

```
// the 'and' is weird
// string query = "from Event e and e.IsDeleted = 0 ";
// should be
string query = "from Event e WHERE e.IsDeleted = 0 ";
```

The second, HQL is about the C# properties *(not columns)*. So, what seems confusing to me here is the string/names inconsistency

```
// here we get from upper layers the string 'DateCreated'
case "DateCreated":
    // while here we do order over the 'CreatedOn'
    query = query + " order by e.CreatedOn ";
```

These are the hints, which could be seen without more details

*(I mean: the HQL in NHibernate is general working correctly. The OrderBy clause is implemented as expected)*